# C# - Publish .exe

Tags: c#, build, exe

I am just about done with my first Visual C#.net application, and I'm trying to publish it.

When I go to Project > Publish, all I seem to be able to make is a set of folders and files containing:

- Application Files (File folder)
- setup (Application) APP NAME
- (ClickOnce Application)

Is there any way that I can specify my deployment as a single file that contains all of the required install data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do not use `Publish`, use the File -> new project -> `Setup Wizard` to create a `setup.exe` file which will install your windows application.

Comment: Does this provide support for an auto-updater feature? I'm just wondering.

Comment: If you want automatic updates, check out ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: @Davide Piras: How then do I add my existing project to the installer? I only noticed a step for additional files, such as READMEs, of which I have none.

Comment: 'Publish' produces a ClickOnce application which does have autoupdate, but also has a variety of potentially annoying limitations.

Comment: @Josh, try to follow the Setup Wizard and read documentation about it, you can add the Primary output of your windows application to it and it's simple to use yet you can customize the dialogs of the generated setup wizard and also configure it so that when you install a newer version the previous one is silently uninstalled etc...

Comment: @DavidePiras: This helped me. I misunderstood that you add a new project to the current project. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c%23-application-visual-studio-setup-project/

Comment: @DavidePiras That link takes me to a gambling(?) website.

Comment: It seems this answer is a bit outdated, at least for VS 2022. I cannot find "New Project" under "File" and there seems to be no "Setup Wizard" option anywhere in VS.

Answer (score 3):

Publish is used mainly for [publishing websites (such as ASP.NET content)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  You can create a desktop installer by a special type of Visual Studio project.  You can find it (in Visual Studio 2010) here:

`File > New > Project > (Installed Templates: Other Project Types > Setup and Deployment < Visual Studio Installer) > Setup Wizard`

Comment: It seems this answer is a bit outdated, at least for Visual Studio 2022. I cannot find "New Project" under "File" and there seems to be no "Setup Wizard" option anywhere in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this:

Make sure your project is targeting .NET 5 or a later version

Open your project in Visual Studio, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, and select Publish.

You can either create a new publish profile or use an existing one.

(To Create new publish profile):

Step 1
[image]

Step 2
[image]

Step 3
[image]

then
In the Publish wizard, select the Show all setting. select the Deployment Mode as Self-contained. Choose the target runtime for your application. This could be win-x64 for a 64-bit Windows application. In the 'File Publish Option' section, check the 'Produce single file' option, and then proceed with the publish.

[image]

Comment: This solution helps you have a standalone executable file that can be used independently without any additional files.